# Running script file from Python interpreter

Tags: python, import

In Python interpreter (Python 3.9.2, Win 10) I've already run

> > > import numpy as np

In a plain text file "myscript.py" in the same (current working) directory is the single line

A = np.array((1,2,3,4))

Running at the interpreter

> > > import myscript

gives the error message (in part)
NameError: name 'np' is not defined

I'm sure it's a namespace-ish thing; I'm a long-time R user just starting to explore Python. Just puzzled why np isn't defined, despite having imported that alias at the interpreter previously.

I'm looking for something equivalent to R's source() function whereby I can have the Python interpreter and the source code text file both open, make changes to the source code file, and rerun it in the interpreter with each such change. (I'm aware of using importlib.reload() for the subsequent re-runs, but the "name undefined" issue keeps me from getting out of the starting gate.)

Comment: Modules are namespaces. You can add a module to your current namespace by doing `import modulename` (or everything from the module `from modulename import *`, but the current namespace isn't the global context for the imported module. In other words, each module considers itself to be the global namespace.

Answer (score 0):

If you import `myscript` in the interpreter, Python just executes that code (similar to using `python3 myscript`). If you haven't put `import numpy as np` at the top of your script, then `np` *is* not defined. Because it is not defined.

So to start off, you need to add that line to `myscript.py`:

```py
import numpy as np

A = np.array((1,2,3,4))
```

Then you can run your script interactively in the interpreter with

```py
>>> exec(open('myscript.py').read())
```

or, as you suggested, with

```py
>>> import importlib
>>> import myscript
>>> importlib.reload(myscript)
```

The first two lines must be at the start of your interpreter session, and everytime you edit `myscript.py` you run `importlib.reload(myscript)`.